# How do I make a stack of divs that stick to the bottom of their parent div?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a simple messaging app UI.  I am trying to make the messages anchor to the bottom of the screen like most modern messaging applications.  So far, here is the bare bones of my messaging UI:

> HTML

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="contact-list">
    contacts here
  </div>
  <div class="conversation-area">
    <div class="msg msg-them">this is Alison</div>
    <div class="msg msg-me">this is me!</div>
    <div class="msg msg-them">you are so cool! :)</div>
    <div class="msg msg-them">seriously.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> SASS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.main-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
  .contact-list{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #aaa;
        border-right: 2px solid #777;
  }
  .conversation-area{
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #ccc;

      .msg{
        vertical-align: bottom;
        border: 1px solid black;
        &-them{
          background-color: blue;
          float: left;
          max-width: 250px;
          display: inline;
          clear: both;
        }

        &-me{
          background-color: red;
          float: right;
          max-width: 250px;
          display: inline;
          clear: both;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Whenever a new message comes in, I'll insert it as the last child of the `.conversation-area` div.  I have the messages stacking just like I want them.  I just need to make them stick to the bottom of the `.conversation-area` div.

I've tried messing with position attributes of both the parent and child divs, as well as tried to get vertical-align to work, but so far I haven't gotten it functioning.

How can I make my messaging app look exactly the same EXCEPT the messages stick to the bottom rather than the top?

Here's the jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/63vufn7u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:bottom;`

I have made some changes to your code but im sure you can adapt now its working:

```css
.main-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
.contact-list {
  width:25%;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
#conversation-area {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: steelblue;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.msg {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}
.msg p {
  border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.msg-me {
  text-align: left;
}

.msg-me p {
  border-radius:15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.msg-them {
  text-align: right;
}

.msg-them p {
  border-radius:15px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="contact-list">
    Contacts
  </div>
  <div id="conversation-area">
  <div class="msg msg-them"><p>this is Alison</p></div>
    <div class="msg msg-me"><p>this is me!</p></div>
    <div class="msg msg-them"><p>you are so cool! :)</p></div>
    <div class="msg msg-them"><p>seriously.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was curious as I was looking at the same approach is there any way to use this method with a percentage based layout like before (no fixed height definition)?  Nice solution though and I like the styling that was the only piece tripping me up.

Comment: If you are looking for somthing a little more feature rich and well styled may I recommend http://www.bypeople.com/css-chat/ specifically: http://codepen.io/Momciloo/pen/bEdbxY?utm_source=bypeople

Answer (score 0):

Your friendly neighborhood Flexbox solution:

On the container, you could also use the `justify-content` property to align it's contents to the bottom:

```
.conversation-area {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

Learn more about flexbox here: http://www.flexboxin5.com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found is to use `flex-direction: column-reverse;`.

The drawback to `flex-direction: column;` is that it starts you at the top and you have to scroll down for older texts. And that's not how chat app interfaces tend to work.

`column-reverse` makes the texts stick to the bottom. The tradeoff is you have to insert your messages in ascending time stamp order instead of reversed like you normally would, because flex-box does the reversing in css. Same with any animations. So new text bubble animation would be applied to the `:first child` rather than the `:last child`.

Here's an example without animations: https://jsfiddle.net/ut1Lybsj/1/

```html
<style>
  .container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  .container div {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
<div style="background:red;">First Item<br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada semper purus, non rutrum nulla mollis id. Nunc faucibus hendrerit nunc, eu rhoncus nisi congue non. </div>
  
<div style="background: skyblue;">Second Item<br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada semper purus, non rutrum nulla mollis id. Nunc faucibus hendrerit nunc, eu rhoncus nisi congue non. </div>

<div style="background: green;">Third Item<br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada semper purus, non rutrum nulla mollis id. Nunc faucibus hendrerit nunc, eu rhoncus nisi congue non. </div>

</div>
```